# Cannot include existing header file in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to include an header file, which I added to my project. I right-clicked on my project->Add->Existing element. But when I want to include that header file, MSVC says that the file could not be found. Did I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to add the header file to the solution folder.

Comment: If you mean you had to copy the file to the directory your solution is in, you're not actually forced to, as long as your #include "x.h" uses the correct relative path ( or the full path name, but you don't normally want to #include using full path name )